# Undo and Redo in core data cocoa application - is this normal behaviour?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have core data cocoa application. I was trying different ways to enable the undo and redo option using bindings, and I couldn't find a way how to do it. So I make 2 IBActions and I have now the following code: (only the code relevant to the question is posted due the simplicity)

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.mObjContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}

- (IBAction)undoItemHasBeenClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.mObjContext undo];
}

- (IBAction)redoItemHasBeenClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.mObjContext redo];
}
```

Everything is fine with this code, it works just fine. However, what I don't like is that even if I don't make any changes, the undo and redo item menus are active. Shouldn't those 2 options be grayed if I have done no changes so there is nothing to undo or redo?

Am I doing something wrong here or this is normal behavior? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu items are enabled because `undoItemHasBeenClicked` and `redoItemHasBeenClicked` can be executed. The default undo and redo menu items should work if the delegate of the window implements `windowWillReturnUndoManager:` and returns the undomanager of the context.