# Can't make undo & redo to work in cocoa core data app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsundomanager

I have problem to implement undo and redo in my core data cocoa application. This is second question that I am asking on same topic, ([you can read my first question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248999/undo-and-redo-in-core-data-cocoa-application-is-this-normal-behaviour)) and even that I get solid advice on my first question, I still can't make undo and redo to work.

Anyway...here is my current code:

Here is the relevant code from MainWindowController.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mObjContext;
@property AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

Here is the code from the MainWindowController.m file:

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"
@interface MainWindowController () <NSWindowDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.mObjContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    [[self window]setDelegate:self];
    [self windowWillReturnUndoManager:self.window];
}

- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window
{
    return [[self document] undoManager];
}

@end
```

My window has the following Outlets in connection inspector: delegate: File's owner

Menu: MainMenu

Whenever I make changes in the records in my nstableviews, changes are recorded but undo and redo menu items remain gray. I placed break point in windowWillReturnUndoManager, but I can't see any undoManager returned there...Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is finally solved. I add new edit menu item, while keeping the old one. When I make change in the record, the new menu item had undo item available and worked. Redo worked too.

So I delete the old edit menu item, and now everything works like a charm. Too bad that I didn't try this earlier, but....

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the undoManager of the document (which is probably nil) instead of the undoManager of the managed object context. Change `windowWillReturnUndoManager` to

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window
{
    return self.mObjContext.undoManager;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happen after I change the code...Undo and Redo are still grayed out, even I make changes, and those changes has been saved.

Comment: How do you make changes?

Comment: I change the record for example. After saving, I should be able to make an undo, but no, the menu items (undo and redo) are both greyed out.

Comment: Do you use NSArrayController and bindings or a datasource?

Comment: NSArrayController and bindings.

Comment: Is `windowWillReturnUndoManager` called when you open the Edit menu and when you start editing?

Comment: Yes, it is. I added NSLog message there and if I start editing the field, the NSLog message is displayed.

Comment: And when you open the Edit menu? Is it the default standard Edit menu? Is everything else working?

Comment: The Edit menu is the default one, other commands (that I have created in other menu) works. I will check now if the other commands in the edit menu works.

Comment: Something is wrong somewhere but I can't say what and where.